# BeagleBoard cycle counter

Tags: linux, module, cycle, counter, beagleboard

I do not succed to activate the cycle counter registrer on my beagleboard.
I've read that I have to compile a linux module but I do not succed too.

my linux kernel is
2.6.35.8-l7

This is the linux version proposed by beagleboard
http://elinux.org/BeagleBoard

so I suppose that I'm not the only one user of this version.

Can anybody give me the compiled module or explain me how I can compile the module !
gcc always tell me it miss some header.

Thank's

Comment: What module are you trying to compile, how does its Makefile looks and how are you triyng to build it?

Answer (score 0):

If compiler tells you about missing header, most probably you don't have kernel headers installed.

If your distro is Debian read this: http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-common-tasks.html